# Paypal v2 API how to get transaction data and also how to make a refund

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

My problem is as follows:
I have a business paypal account where I have a list of transactions made by my clients (buying products on my webpage). I store their orders info via paypal IPN which only sends me the transaction ID of the order. So I store this transaction ID on my database among other basic data.
Now I need 2 things:

- Retrieve the transaction data via php code.
- Make refunds of any transaction also via php code.

I see Paypal API v2 is the recommended as the v1 is gonna be abandoned. I'm using Checkout-PHP-SDK:
https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

But I'm facing problems only trying to get any transaction data. I read that in order to get the data i cannot use the transaction ID but the order ID instead. But how can use an order ID that I ignore?, because from paypal IPN I only receive transaction ID and that's only what I have. So how can I get the order id from this transaction id?. I know I'm probably confusing terms so sorry in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you capture an order, the immediate API response already contains all information about the transaction -- including the transaction ID at `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`. There is no need to use the old IPN service. Your integration should not depend on IPN in any way, that is bad design.

For refunds, use that transaction (capture) id with the [v2/payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/api/payments/v2/#captures_refund)

Comment: Thanks Preston PHX for your fast answer. You are right. In fact I tested sandbox environment and I saw what you mention (transaction ID is at purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id). But the problem now is that I have to totally redesign the way I store the payments. As you say, abandone IPN (why is a bad design?) and use the new API, but I have no time for that at my company. Do you think I have any other alternative or just assume the change you are proposing?.

Comment: IPN is a separate, asynchronous notification. It adds several points of failure, and there is no reason to depend on it. The orders capture response already has everything you need to populate your database